VS Code Jupyter: Code Suggestions Stuck in JavaScript Environment After Switching Back to Python
When I use npm to install the ijavascript kernel and switch to it in the Jupyter environment in VS Code, then switch back to the Python environment, the code suggestions are still those from the JS environment. How can I fix this?
I have reinstalled VSCode, but the problem still remains.
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
